# issues with the implementation of the normal equation in Python

Tags: python

I am using a dataset in Python about houses available in:

http://www.rossmanchance.com/iscam2/data/housing.txt

and tried to make an implementation of the linear regression as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 

data= np.genfromtxt("housing.txt",dtype='O',delimiter="\t",skip_header=True)
X=data[:,0].astype(np.float)
y=data[:,1].astype(np.float)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
lr=linear_model.LinearRegression()
X_trainrs=X_train.reshape(-1,1)
y_trainrs=y_train.reshape(-1,1)
lr.fit(X_trainrs,y_trainrs)
print "intercept ",lr.intercept_
yfit=lr.predict(X_test.reshape(-1,1))
plt.scatter(X_test,y_test)
plt.plot(X_test,yfit)
```

The program works fine, and I get a plot of the linear regression for this dataset. The problem I have is when I want to implement the normal equation. I have done something like this:

```
ft=(X_trainrs.T.dot(X_trainrs))
inv=np.linalg.inv(ft)
yfit2=X_test.reshape(-1,1).dot(inv)
plt.plot(X_test,yfit2)
```

The problem that I have is that the value that is plotted is a flat line, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could understand, in the second part of your code you are trying to obtain the coefficients by solving a system of linear equations and then use it on the test data to generate predictions.

What you want to do is solve for coefficients in

> X * coeff = y

```
where X = [x1, 1]  y = [y1]  coeff = [slope     ]
          [x2, 1]      [y2]          [intercept ]
          [x3, 1]      [y3]
          [ :  :]      [ :]
          [xn, 1]      [yn]
```

The analytical solution to this equation is given by:

> coeff = inv(X.T * X) * X.T * y = pseudo-inverse(X) * y

To generate predictions using this solution, you would do

> y_test = X_test * coeff

where X_test has that extra column with ones in it.

There are 2 issues with your code:

1. You need to add the column containing ones to X_trainrs.
2. The equation you have used for generating the prediction is incorrect.

This is probably what you want:

```
xx = np.hstack([X_trainrs, np.ones((X_trainrs.shape[0], 1))]) # append ones
coeff = np.linalg.pinv(xx).dot(y_trainrs) # computes inv(X.T * X) * X.T * y
xx_test = np.hstack([X_test.reshape(-1, 1), np.ones((X_test.shape[0], 1))])
yfit2 = xx_test.dot(coeff)
plt.plot(X_test, yfit2)
```

You can avoid coding the logic for obtaining `coeff` manually by using `np.linalg.lstsq` which does all of this for you.

```
coeff, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(xx, y_trainrs)
```